# What symptoms call for an immediate trip to the doctor?

Tags: infant, health

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you know when it is time to take a child to the Doctor?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-you-know-when-it-is-time-to-take-a-child-to-the-doctor)

As a new mother, I tend to be very worried. I'm always afraid I might be missing something, or not noticing an important symptom. I was wondering if there are symptoms that call for immediate contact with a doctor. For example, when I went for my first visit to my baby's pediatrician, she told me that if I ever see green in my baby's spit-up I should immediately call her. Are there any other signs I should look out for? I'd love to compile a list.

To start:

- Green spitup
- High fever
- (Consistent) Projectile vomiting (a single isolated case is probably perfectly normal)