# What could cause my baby's bedroom to smell like bread after sleep?

Tags: health, bedroom

When my baby is awake it smells normal. But when it sleeps it makes its room smell strongly like freshly baked bread. The room is clean and has no odor when unoccupied. My baby's urine smells normal and the room smells bready when its diaper is clean. My baby's hair and breath don't smell unusual. But morning after morning I wake to the aroma of a freshly baked baguette.

Is it normal for a baby to smell bready? What could cause this odor?

Comment: Do you mean like yeast, perhaps?

Comment: All my kiddo's bowel movements smell like buttered popcorn! Weirder things have happened :)

Comment: Clearly not a medical advice question, but a personal curiosity question (as evidenced by the accepted answer). Vote to reopen so that others are more likely to see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 11yo son's hair has a very strong "scent," not anything specific, like bread, but distinctly "him." His hair tends to be almost waxy, even when clean, and every morning his room smells like...him. No one else in my house can smell it but me, and it's less noticeable when he gets a crew cut in the summer (that's how I know it's his hair). It's possible your baby is the same way...and you are very sensitive to your baby's natural scent like I am. Everybody has a scent, btw, it's just that most people are not consciously aware of them. It's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a [yeast infection](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/oral-thrush---babies/pages/introduction.aspx) - sometimes found combined with [nappy rash](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/Pages/Nappy-rash.aspx).

Best to have a doctor check them out.

See: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/647/11210