# How Can I Tell If My Toddler Has A Cold?

Tags: toddler, sickness

My 21 month old son has had a bad runny nose for the past 2 days. He's been more lethargic than normal, has been eating less than usual, but still has occasional spurts of energetic activity, and also does not have a fever.

I suspect he may have a cold, but the symptoms I've listed are also fairly consistent with allergies too.

How can I tell if the symptoms I'm looking at are signs of a cold?

Comment: Your child may or may not have a cold. And an ear infection. Or not. Or... or... You must realize we can't answer this. When in doubt, that's what your primary care provider is for. FWIW, I was great at diagnosing and treating other people's kids, but when it came to my own, I had no objectivity. Parenting is *very unnerving!*

Comment: ("He's been more lethargic than normal..." Oh, and btw, there's no *normal* level of *lethargy*. If you want to alarm a healthcare provider and guarantee a same day visit, use the word *lethargy* even just once.) There's "less active than usual", there's "sleeping more than usual", etc. But "lethargy" needs to be seen pronto.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I tell if the symptoms I'm looking at are signs of a cold?

You can't.

Even for a medical professional, distinguishing the two can be difficult.

If you suspect the symptoms to be more than a mild cold, or if you want to find out whether your child has an allergy, take them to the doctor.

If you are unsure whether a doctor visit is warranted, do not despair - we have a question for that, too :-).

[How do you know when it is time to take a child to the Doctor?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-you-know-when-it-is-time-to-take-a-child-to-the-doctor)